# transformation works with values from previous line, but should not

Tags: xml, xslt

i have a simple price list in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="example.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<price-items>
<item><name>item 1</name>   <price-b2b vat='no'>10</price-b2b><price-b2c vat='no'>20</price-b2c></item>
<item><name>item 2</name>   <price-b2b vat='yes'>100</price-b2b><price-b2c vat='yes'>200</price-b2c></item>
<item><name>item 3</name>   <price-b2b vat='no'>1000</price-b2b><price-b2c vat='no'>2000</price-b2c></item>
</price-items>
```

the attached stylesheet looks is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet  [
    <!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:decimal-format decimal-separator="," grouping-separator=" "/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:variable name="vat" select="1.21" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<?xml-stylesheet href="example.css" type="text/css"?>
<price-items> <xsl:apply-templates /></price-items>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
<item><xsl:apply-templates /></item>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
<name><xsl:apply-templates /></name>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
<item>
    <xsl:for-each select="price-b2b">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@vat='no'">
            <price-b2b vat="no">b2b excl. VAT: <xsl:value-of select="." />&nbsp;unit(s)</price-b2b>
            <price-b2b vat="yes">b2b s vat <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(/price-items/item/price-b2b * $vat), '# ###,##')" />&nbsp;unit(s)</price-b2b>
            </xsl:when>

            <xsl:when test="@vat='yes'">
            <price-b2b vat="no">b2b excl. VAT: <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(/price-items/item/price-b2b div $vat), '# ###,##')" />&nbsp;unit(s)</price-b2b>
            <price-b2b vat="yes">b2b incl. VAT: <xsl:apply-templates />&nbsp;unit(s)</price-b2b>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>


    <xsl:for-each select="price-b2c">    
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@vat='no'">
        <price-b2c vat="no">b2c excl. VAT: <xsl:apply-templates />&nbsp;unit(s)</price-b2c>
        <price-b2c vat="yes">b2c incl. VAT: <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(/price-items/item/price-b2c * $vat), '# ###,##')" />&nbsp;unit(s)</price-b2c>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="@vat='yes'">
        <price-b2c vat="no">b2c price excl. VAT: <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(/price-items/item/price-b2c div $vat), '# ###,##')" />&nbsp;unit(s)</price-b2c>
        <price-b2c vat="yes">b2c price incl. VAT: <xsl:apply-templates />&nbsp;unit(s)</price-b2c>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>

</item>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output is this (on-the-fly tranform in IE9, and some formatting added here just for clarity):

```
b2b excl. VAT: 10 unit(s)
b2b s vat 12,1 unit(s)
b2c excl. VAT: 20 unit(s)
b2c incl. VAT: 24,2 unit(s)

b2b excl. VAT: 8,26 unit(s)
b2b incl. VAT: 100 unit(s)
b2c price excl. VAT: 16,53 unit(s)
b2c price incl. VAT: 200 unit(s)

b2b excl. VAT: 1000 unit(s)
b2b s vat 12,1 unit(s)
b2c excl. VAT: 2000 unit(s)
b2c incl. VAT: 24,2 unit(s)
```

In the 2nd and 3rd line when the calcualtion is involved, it calculates with values from the first line (first item), not with respective values in the actual line.

Why is that? How do I correct this?

Comment: Wild guess, you are using `/price-items/item/price-b2b` drop the `/` at the beginning as it is telling the XSLT go from the root and downwards, so you are losing your `foreach` position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do the calculations:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(/price-items/item/price-b2b * $vat), '# ###,##')" />
```

this will always give you the price of the first item (technically `/price-items/item/price-b2b` is a node set containing *all* the `price-b2b` elements from *every* item, and when you take the numeric value of a node set with several nodes it uses just the *first* node in the set and ignores the others).

But at this point in the stylesheet the context node you're `for-each`ing over is already a `price-b2b` element, so you should just do something like

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(. * $vat), '# ###,##')" />
```

and likewise for the other three cases.

Comment: thnaks for the reply, i have rewritten it and it works. the reason why i probably (yes, i had tried so many versions that i got lost a ilttel...) used the full path '/price-items/item/price-b2b' was that i was getting NaN with just 'price-b2b'. originally, i did not use the number formatting, but without it ('price-b2b * $vat' for example) i was getting NaN as well, and using just 'number(price-b2b * $vat)' did not help either... the content of the item eelements was always a number (or series of numerlas easily convertible to a number)...

Comment: anyway, it seems to be workign for me now so thanks again for help and explanation.